# What is the right way to escape user input and output data against xss and sql injection

Tags: php

What is the right way to escape user input and output data's against xss and sql injection?
This is the one i wanted to use, i don't know if it is secured.

**This below as input**

```
function check_input($data) {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = strip_tags($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     $data = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     return $data;
}
```

**Then use this below as the output**

```
echo htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

or

```
echo htmlentities($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: Don't apply anti xss/sql injection to *input*

Comment: please how will i format the input function

Comment: what about if i only use this for input " . mysql_real_escape_string($data) . "

Comment: How about `return $data`? Encoding the input is the wrong approach. You use html entity encoding directly before you output it as html and `mysql_real_escape_string` directly before you include it in an SQL statement (or better yet, use parameterized queries)

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong approach. You should not design one function that solved all security problems and then blindly apply it in all situations no matter the context.

How to protect against XSS depends on the context you are outputting to, so you need different functions depending on the context. See the [OWASP XSS cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). That is quite a long read, because XSS is quite a complicated problem. If you want to avoid the complexity of dealing with it, use a framework that helps you take care of it.

Using sanitation to take care of SQLi is a bad idea. Instead, use [prepared statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp). It will help with performance as well, so it is a win-win.